# How to write the following objective function in Gurobi?

Tags: java, model, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

The following is the objective function:

[image]

I have the following Java code:

```
// Create list of variables
List<GRBVar> varList = new ArrayList<>();

// Set objective: maximize log(p) * x
GRBLinExpr expr = new GRBLinExpr();

int counter = 0;

for(Map.Entry<String, Double[]> entry: probabilityLevels.entrySet()) {

    Double[] probs = entry.getValue();

    for (Double prob: probs) {
        GRBVar x = model.addVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "x" + counter); 
        expr.addTerm(Math.log(prob), x);
        varList.add(x);
    }
}

model.setObjective(expr, GRB.MAXIMIZE);
```

Update the code

Comment: Is p a decision variable or data? Is z a superscript or an exponent?

Comment: z is just a superscript is not an exponent, and p is just a quantifier, it is a variable that has a known value. I believe the only decision variable is x since the value of x will decide if p is selected or not. Also, I noticed that p can sometimes be 0, which means that log is -Infinity. This messes up the output after I run the MIP solver. Is it possible that my calculations of p are wrong, or is there some feature that the solver could use to cope with this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops look correct, but you are only creating one GRBVar x, instead of creating one GRBVar for each combination of j, k and z.  You should create some data structure to store all these GRBVar objects, and create them as you iterate over the combinations of j, k and z.

Comment: I updated the code now, but I still have the same problem with the log values as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: There is no way to work with +/- Infinity values in an LP/MIP solver like Gurobi.